# Unable to find svn ignore property in order to unignore a file

Tags: svn, ignore

When I run `svn status --no-ignore | grep "I "` I get list of some ignored files and there I can see that the file I want to commit was ignored by some one

```
I    MyProject/subdir/sbudri2/ignoredfile.a
```

I want to unignore it. In order to do that I need to know where it is set so I try recursively finding it with

```
svn pg svn:ignore . -v -R --show-inherited-props
svn pg svn:global-ignores . -v -R --show-inherited-props
svn proplist -v -R . --show-inherited-props
```

Nothing comes up. What else can I try? What am I missing?

Comment: What Subversion client version do you use?

Comment: svn, version 1.10.3 (r1842928)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that seamed to follow me between machines and couldn't shake it.  I finally noticed that in my global ignore settings, there was a space between an extension and the wild card which caused all new files to be ignored.

Running the three commands above received similar results.  The new file showed as ignored, but svn pg didn't provide any information as to why.

Under TortuiseSVN settings, the default Global ignore patters is something like:

```
*.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo __pycache__ *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store [Tt]humbs.db
```

I effectively had a space between the first * and .o that should not have existed.